# Can a monotonic function on $\mathbb R^n$ have a essential discontinuity?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

It is known that for a real monotone function, the [discontinuity must be a jump discontinuity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3228727/monotonic-function-can-only-have-simple-discontinuity)

Now let $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$ and define $x\geq y$ if $x_i\geq y_i$ in all dimensions.

$f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is (weakly) increasing if $x\geq y$ implies $f(x)\geq f(y)$

My question is, can $f$ has an essential discontinuity?

My guess is still no as $f$ is still of bounded variation.

I give two definition for essential discontinuous:

> $f$ is strictly essential discontinuous at $0$ if the directional limit to zero does not exists (and not infinite) for all directional vector $v$.

> $f$ is weakly essential discontinuous at $0$ if the directional limit to zero does not exists (and not infinite) for one directional vector $v$.

Comment: Can you clarify the domain and codomain for $f$? (I assume domain is $\mathbb R^n$ but not sure if $f$ is real valued or $\mathbb R^n$-valued.)

Comment: What do you mean by an essential discontinuity in higher dimensions?

Comment: @MW Real-valued, I'll add it into the body :)

Comment: @MoisheKohan The limit does not exist at the point of discontinuity

Comment: Then jump discontinuity is also essential, which is not what you want. The 1-variable definition of an essential discontinuity is nonexistence of left or right hand limits. But I am not sure what this would mean in higher dimensions. And your edit is very unclear, what do you mean by a "direction?" Do you mean a limit along a line segment terminating at the given point (say, $0$)?

Comment: @MoisheKohan You are right. I must clarify that the directional limit does not exist.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes I think you are right. Do you think defining the directional limit via directional vector would work? I learnt the term "directional limit" here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Discontinuity.html

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4798161/is-this-a-proper-definition-of-essential-discontinuity-for-f-mathbb-rn-to-mat

Comment: I have no idea, you should modify your question by posting the definition that you have in mind. Comments are not meant for this.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to give an example for an increasing function that is weakly essentially discontinuous.

Let $b\in\mathbb R_+$. Let $a\in [-0.5,0.5]$. Let $f:\mathbb R^2_+\to\mathbb R$.

Define $f$ using three cases:

$f\big((\frac{1}{2}-a)(1,0)+(\frac12 +a)(0,1)\big)=b(\sin(1/a))$ and $=0$ if $a=0$.

$f\big((\frac{1}{2}-a)(b,0)+(\frac12 +a)(0,b)\big)=b$ if $b>1$

$f\big((\frac{1}{2}-a)(b,0)+(\frac12 +a)(0,b)\big)=b-2$ if $b<1$

The intuition is that, there is an essential discontinuity at $(\sqrt2/2,\sqrt2/2)$.

The limit does not exist in the direction of $(1,-1)$ or $(-1,1)$ but the limit seems exist in other directions.

---

For my definition of "strictly essential continuity", I don't think it works for increasing functions.