# Is this a proper definition of essential discontinuity for $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$: the directional limit does not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

I went over a few post on this forum and people cited a page on Mathworld saying that discontuity of a $\mathbb R^n$ function is [hard to define](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Discontinuity.html).

However, that Mathworld page does implicitly defined a type directional limit and a type of essential discontinuity:

[image]

However, that page does not rigorously define what is directional limit.

**Question: ** what is a proper definition for directional limit and essential discontinuity?

I try to define my own:

> Say the limit at zero via directional vector $v$ is $\lim_{x\to
> > 0+\epsilon v}f(x)$.

I also try to define essential discontinuity:

> $f$ is strictly essentially discontinuous at $0$ if the directional limit to zero does not exists (and not infinite) for all directional vector $v$.

> $f$ is weakly essentially discontinuous at $0$ if the directional limit to zero does not exists (and not infinite) for one direction directional vector $v$.

I also learn that a directional limit might be more complicated that the directional limit via a vector. For example, there are things called "radical limit", "nontangential limit", "stolz angle limit".